# Using .apk files in a Java project, or the reverse

Tags: android, jar, apk

There are a few questions on SO about using .jar files in an Android project. But I am wondering if the reverse is possible - is it possible to use .apk files in a Java desktop project?
The reason for this is that I created a Java desktop app for object database management, but it needs the model classes from whichever application database it is looking at. With an object database, you need the model classes to define you database schemas. Side question - forgive me for my ignorance but can you run a runnable .apk in a desktop environment? something like this:
http://www.techday.in/how-to-run-android-apk-apps-on-computer/

Anyway, my goal is to kick off my personal object manager program from an individual android application. So in that case the .apk files would have to be able to talk with .jar files. If that fails, I could try just the opposite - kick off the jar file, and use the -vm argument as a location of the .apk files to put in the classpath. Either way. Which is easier? ---> .apk files in a Java program's classpath or .jar files in an Android program's path? Please, just expound away, I want all your thoughts.

Comment: this might help you https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/

Answer (score 3):

APKs contain DEX files, not Java Classes so you would need to translate from one VM file format DEX Davlik to another. The link you provided is for Bluestack's Android VM which would run a APK as it is running the Android OS. If you want to look up how VirtualBox does things that would be the closest match.

The source for Android projects do use standard JAR files for libraries and class files are generated as part of the build process however once you start to package into something you can put on a Android device/emulator/environment you are in a different world.

However as the DEX file format is open-sourced, what you are trying to do isn't impossible, but it might be easier to use the intermediate class files instead.